# Find the value of $λ$ such that $v − u$ is orthogonal to $w$

Tags: matrices

Let $v$ and $w$ be any two non-zero vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Let $u = λw$ for some real number λ. Find the value of $λ$ such that $v − u$ is orthogonal to $w$.

I dont know how to use vector v.
There are nothing about v from the question.
Somebody help me:D

Comment: Set $(v-u)\cdot w=(v-\lambda w)\cdot w=0$ and then solve for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

$(v-u)w=0$ must hold for orthogonality;
$(v- \lambda w)w= vw - \lambda(w^2)=0$

Comment: ya, i know, and then? i dont know how to deal with vw.